# C# OxyPlot: How to display point values on chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, oxyplot

can anyone suggest how to display the values of the points on the chart? something like that. Chart:

[image: chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `LabelFormatString` property on your series. This lets you specify what to display, and how to display it.

To display just the y values like in your screenshot:

```
  // Show the y value with 1 decimal place.
  series.LabelFormatString = "{1:F1}";
```

[image: y value]

```
  // Or if you wanted to show (x, y).
  series.LabelFormatString = "({0:F1}, {1:F1})";
```

[image: (x,y) picture]